.NET Framework version requirement is higher than the project target while using 'System.Web.dll'
I have recently gotten an error on my .NET Project:

The .NET Framework version required by assembly 'System.Web.dll' or
one of its dependencies is higher than the project target .NET
Framework version. Do you want to add this reference to your project
anyway?


I have tried changing the Framework, this did not help. It has worked fine the day before. Upon installing Visual Studio on another computer the same error was shown.

Firstly, dont post errors in a form of image, or atleast give it here in a text form (together with the image- ok).
Secondly, its just an warning that says that referenced .dll doesnt match the .NET Framework choosen in project properties as a target. Didnt you updated some NuGet Packages, or maybe uninstalled/installed some frameworks SDK?

I have edited the post / proposed changes and written out the error message: The .NET Framework version required by assembly 'System.Web.dll' or one of its dependencies is higher than the project target .NET Framework version. Do you want to add this reference to your project anyway? Posted a possible related fix. I will vote to close this as a duplicate question. It also needs a bit more improvement. Maybe add the .NET settings/web.config

This question is similar to: Higher .NET Framework Version for System.Net.Http than Project. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Looks like you're trying to add Web Forms controls to ASP.NET Core application. That will not work. Web Forms is not compatible with ASP.NET Core, only the older ASP.NET platform.

After looking around StackOverflow I have found a possible solution to this issue. It seems to be related to the Framework version installed on your machine.
The gist is, when targeting a lower version of .NET while a newer one is installed AspNetCompiler notices that the code takes some dependencies from the GAC, which correspond to a higher .NET than the codebase target. Hence the error message.

Your issue could have the same root cause - your local machine has .NET Framework of the higher version than the one you target. Either uninstall it or modify the references in the web.config that control compilation of the embedded C# code.


Answer by Mark on Higher .NET Framework Version for System.Net.Http than Project

